# Filtering out retweets with the search API

Tags: python, twitter

Do you know why

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23work&result_type=recent&rpp=1&filter:retweets
```

is still displaying `RT` messages?

eg

```
u'RT @1YOUNGSCOOTER: F*** a friend be about your business #work'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That tweet is not a retweet, it is merely a tweet with the text `RT` at the start. You can see this [on the original tweet](https://twitter.com/moreJASplease/status/311761463356293120), there is *no* 'Retweeted by' text on it.

If I send a tweet with the text `RT @somename: this is not a retweet` you would see it too. Just because a tweet starts with `RT` does not make it a proper retweet.

Your query is working just fine.